# How do I navigate this nested hash without knowing the randomly generated string by ActionController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this params hash:

```
> profile_params[:videos_attributes]
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"1479515357347"=><ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://vimeo.com/some-awesome-video", "official"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>
```

I am trying to get to the `vimeo_url` key, but not quite sure how to do that:

I tried these:

```
> profile_params[:videos_attributes][:vimeo_url]
=> nil
[14] pry(#<ProfilesController>)> profile_params[:videos_attributes]['vimeo_url']
=> nil
```

The only thing that works is this:

```
> profile_params[:videos_attributes]['1479515357347']
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://vimeo.com/some-awesome-video", "official"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>
```

But the issue with this is that I believe the string is generated by Rails and I don't know how to reference that from my controller.

**Edit 1**

Per [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html), I even tried the following:

```
> profile_params[:videos_attributes].fetch(:vimeo_url)
ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: vimeo_url
```

**Edit 2**

Here is the form (truncated for brevity ofcourse) that generates the `videos_attributes` that I am trying to extract.

```
    <%= simple_form_for @profile, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>

      <h3 class="text-center">Videos</h3>

      <div id="videos" class="text-center">    
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :videos do |video| %>
          <%= render 'video_fields', f: video %>
        <% end %>
        <div class="links">
          <%= link_to_add_association 'Add Video', f, :videos, class: "btn btn-success add-grade-button" %>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

And the `_video_fields.html.erb` partial is here:

```
      <h4>Vimeo</h4>
          <%= f.input :vimeo_url, as: :text, label: false, input_html: { style: "width: 60%", rows: 1 }, class: 'form-control' %>

            <label class="control-label">Official Video?</label>
              <%= f.input_field :official, as: :radio_buttons, class: 'form-control' %>


  <%= link_to_remove_association f do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
  <% end %>
```

**Edit 3**

```
> profile_params[:videos_attributes].key?(:vimeo_url)
=> false
> profile_params[:videos_attributes].values
=> [<ActionController::Parameters {"vimeo_url"=>"https://vimeo.com/some-awesome-video", "official"=>"true", "_destroy"=>"false"} permitted: true>]
```

Not sure how to iterate over the latter to extract the value for `vimeo_url` which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Are you generating this form? Where is the request coming from?

Comment: @JaimeRodas This request is coming from my `edit` action. The form looks like this: `<%= simple_form_for @profile, html: { class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>`

Comment: Could you post the whole form? I don't get how action controller could generate a random string. In any case, you can iterate over a hash by doing something like `profile_params[:videos_attributes].each { |key, value| value['vimeo_url'] }`

Comment: You may try `profile_params[:videos_attributes].key?(:vimeo_url)`. If not, map through the `profile_params[:videos_attributes].values` and check if it has the `...key?(:vimeo_url)`. In, this way, you don't have to deal with the random string.

Comment: I had actually tried the `.key?(:vimeo_url)` before, but it never worked. When you say `map through` the `.values`, what do you mean? I tried doing that, and I got a 1 record array that included that hash. I have updated the question to reflect the results from both of these queries.

Comment: have you tried profile_params[:videos_attributes]["vimeo_url"] yet?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a strong params issue?

In order to permit nested params you need to do the following in your profiles_controller:

```
  private

  def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(videos_attributes: {:vimeo_url})
  end
```

Comment: That's how my `profile_params` looks. It's not a strong params issue. The issue is figuring out how to select a subhash value without knowing the parent `id` to get to the subhash. I actually figured it out. I will add an answer a bit later.

Comment: Ah sorry - then I completely misunderstood your question